# What is meaning of the linear independence over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ of a subset of $\Bbb C^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S = \{(1 + i, 2 i, 2), (1, 1 + i, 1 − i)\} ⊂ \mathbb{C}^ 3$ . Check the linear independence of $S$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

I failed to understand, what this question actually means. What is the meaning of `linear independence of $S$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$'? If someone can please break down the question and explain in detail, it would be great as I am very new in linear algebra and I lack rigorous proofs and terminlogies.

Comment: Have you seen the definition of linear independence? What part of the definition do you not understand?

Comment: @Trebor Ik the definition but what is "S over R" means? The field of scalars is R?

Comment: @Trebor If thats the case, how will I proceed with the solution if field is $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: $S$ si linearly independent over $\mathbb R$ (resp. $\mathbb C$) if $\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}(\text{span}_{\mathbb R}S)=2$ (resp. $\text{dim}_{\mathbb C}(\text{span}_{\mathbb C}S)=2$). Can you see the difference now?

Comment: $\{u,v\}\subset\Bbb C^n$ is linearly *dependent* over $K$ ($K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$) iff there exists a *non-zero* pair $(\lambda,\mu)\in K^2$ s.t. $\lambda u+\mu v=\vec0$. In your example, you will find such pairs in $\Bbb C^2$ but none in $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

"The linear independence of $S$ over $\mathbb{R}$" means that $\mathbb{R}$ is the field of scalars. In other words, you need to find two real numbers $a$ and $b$ (both not equal to zero), such that:
$$
a(1+i,2i,2)+b(1,1+i,1−i)=0
$$

The idea of the exercise is to notice that linear independence depends on the field of scalars. In this case, with $\mathbb{R}$ as the field, the vectors are not independent. However, if you use $\mathbb{C}$ as the field, the vectors are independent.